# How to override style of single RichFaces component

Tags: css, xhtml, richfaces, styling

I need to override a single RichFaces component. I have a simpleTogglePanel below.

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel headerClass="toggleheadder" switchType="client" label="Status">
    <f:facet name="closeMarker">
        <h:graphicImage value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/closeMarker.png" style="cursor:pointer">
        </h:graphicImage>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="openMarker">
        <h:graphicImage value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/openMarker.png" style="cursor:pointer">
    </h:graphicImage>
    </f:facet>
</rich:simpleTogglePanel>
```

According to the Richfaces document, I can override an entire class's style using CSS like this
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#customstyles

```
.rich-stglpanel-body {
text-align:left;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

The only problem with this is that it changes every togglePanel's style on the page when I only need to change one. Does anyone know how to change this attribute for a single RichFaces element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [simpleTogglePanel doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/simpleTogglePanel.html) you can specify value for `bodyClass` and `headerClass` attributes. Simple create your style and use it as value for `bodyClass` attribute in your panel.

Comment: This worked, except that it changed the behavior of my toggle pannel, and now it won't overflow and make more room for itself when I open the toggle panel and it sits on top of another component.